# Page in pagesRoute are sometimes reloaded when using appdir with pages route in Nextjs13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a project that used pagesRoute before. Currently i have built a few more pages but i want to use Appdir instead of continue building in pagesRoute (so i enable appdir in next.config.js file). After completing the new pages in Appdir, when I checked again, I found that the pages in pagesRoute sometimes reload the page when redirecting. When i disable appdir in next.config.js
that problem also goes away, pages on pagesRoute work as expected.

My pj struct :
[pj struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW7X7.png)

I don't know what's going on, am i doing something wrong when using Appdir with pagesRoute?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.